# How do I get auto-wiring to work in symfony/dependency-injection?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a couple of example classes under the DiTest namespace;

```
namespace DiTest;

class Transport
{
    public function send($mail)
    {
        echo $mail . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Mail Sent';
    }
}

class Mailer
{
    protected $transport;

    public function __construct(Transport $transport)
    {
        $this->transport = $transport;
    }

    public function send($mail)
    {
        if ($this->transport) {
            $this->transport->send($mail);
        } else {
            echo 'No transport set!' . PHP_EOL;
        }
   }
}
```

Then I have this yaml config file;

```
services:
    transport:
        class: DiTest\Transport
    mailer:
        class: DiTest\Mailer
        autowire: true
```

Finally I have this in index.php

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '\src'));
$loader->load('services.yml');

$mailer = $container->get('mailer');
$mailer->send('Hello world!');
```

It tries to instantiate the Mailer class without passing in the constructor argument. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

How are we supposed to debug autowiring problems?

Comment: I can answer the last question: debug autowire by not using autowire.  Are you using S2.8?

Comment: I think autowire should only be used for rapid prototyping. I am only using dependency-injection, config and yaml. They are all version 3.2. I just wanted to take a look at how symfony's di container works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$container->compile();` before trying to get the mailer service for all of the autowired references to be resolved.